# Correct pronunciation of "Qty"

Tags: pronunciation, abbreviations

How to pronounce "Qty"?

```
ku-ti-ai
```

or

```
ku-ti-why
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's an abbreviation for "quantity", and I would pronounce it by saying the actual word.

`kwan - teh - tee`

Comment: IPA: [kwɒn.tə.ti] (or [kwɒn.ə.ɾi] — casual)

Comment: @Kosmonaut - Thanks. I have to learn how to do that sometime.